# Shared Preferences KEY_FIRST_RUN is not working in android 1.6?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using the following code to check the application is first time running or not

```
SharedPreferences pref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
if (!pref.contains(KEY_FIRST_RUN)) {
    Some operation
}
pref.edit().putBoolean(KEY_FIRST_RUN, false).commit();
```

It works all the android versions except android 1.6

Please any one help me any error in my program

Give me some suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
private static String KEY_FIRST_RUN = "";
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (!sharedPreferences.contains("KEY_FIRST_RUN")) {
        KEY_FIRST_RUN = "something";
        Log.d("First", "First run!");
    } else {
        Log.d("Second...", "Second run...!");
    }

    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("KEY_FIRST_RUN", KEY_FIRST_RUN);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: (+1) Thank you for the solution. I did it without `String KEY_FIRST_RUN`, but with `editor.putBoolean(NAME_OF_THE_KEY, true)`.