# how to disable activities after first start

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

i an developping an app for android and i want to "disable" or "hide" some activitys after my start.

i tried it with the shared preferences... but it somehow didnt work...

```
// First Start
    SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(mPrefs.getBoolean("firstLaunch", true)) {

        mPrefs.edit().putBoolean("firstLaunch", false);


    }
```

in my head my idea would look like that:

on first start:

- enter the name (activity 1)
- enter two friends (activity 2)
- menu (activity 3)

when its not the first start is should start like that

- menu

i hope you can help me

Comment: commit() should be called after the putBoolean() method...

Comment: where is **commit();**?

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792736/shared-preferences-key-first-run-is-not-working-in-android-1-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with `SharedPreferences`! But adding an entry is only half the way. You will also have to check this entry at the start of the application. Then it will work.

And you have to call `mPrefs.commit()` after adding the entry...

Comment: so i have to add that at the top of the onCreate methode and then it will work? (i know i still have to call the intent of the 3rd activity)

Comment: correct. just check if the entry is true, and then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a **commit()** call in your preferences Editor.

This:

```
mPrefs.edit().putBoolean("firstLaunch", false);
```

should look more like this:

```
mPrefs.edit().putBoolean("firstLaunch", false);
mPrefs.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to load a function or activity just one time

```
public void onResume()
{
SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(mPrefs.getBoolean("firstLaunch", true))
//here you add whatever you want to do one time

mPrefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrunas12", false).commit();
}
```

Comment: y do you do this in onResume and not onCreate?