# Shared Preferences - First time check if empty

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm just working with SP's and trying to check when a button is clicked if it is the first time the user uses the app.
Below code is what I've tried but it does not enter the if and bring me to the next intent.

any ideas?

Thanks

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    myPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, 0);
}

public void loginBtn(View v)
    {
    EditText editText =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText editText2 =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameID);
    if(myPreferences.equals(0))
    {
        if(editText.getText().toString().equals(userName) && editText2.getText().toString().equals(password) )
                {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,ChangePassword.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
    }
```

Comment: Have you googled it ? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792736/shared-preferences-key-first-run-is-not-working-in-android-1-6

Comment: You might be interested in using a library for this such as [TypedPreferences](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/TypedPreferences).

Answer (score 0):

```
String  myPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, 0);
```

**and in if condition**

```
if(myPreferences.equalsIgnoreCase(0))
```